# JavaScript image pairing AI like Quick, Draw

Tags: javascript, image, artificial-intelligence

I was messing around with Quick, Draw! and was thinking about ways to make my own Quick, Draw!. Is there a library that has accurate image comparison like Quick, Draw! and a website that has some drawings of random objects?